# Should I Convert Media Files Before Uploading and What is This Practice Called?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, cdn

I have a web application that asks users to upload images and videos. A database table contains the URI of the file and the resolved internet media type of the file.

I would like to store these images in a common image format and likewise for video and audio as well as reduce the amount of storage space that my application uses in the content delivery network.

> What is a good practice for `converting`/`compressing`/`resizing` media files before
>   uploading them to the content delivery network and inserting the URI
>   into the database?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the images are commonly optimized before uploading to reduce the size.

In case of images a tool like:  http://jpeg-optimizer.com/
are recommended to reduce the size.. You can look for more tools that provide best results in quantity (size) and quality

Answer (score 0):

> What is a good practice for converting/compressing/resizing media files before uploading them to the content delivery network and inserting the URI into the database?

Short answer: This totally depends on the type of data you're serving to your visitors. With regards to images: Use image sizes that are the same resolution as your content is being displayed(There are many tools that can help with this). General rule of thumb: the smaller (filesize) the better.

It's common practise to optimise your files for web-use before you start sending them off to your users. Enabling gzip compression on your server can also speed up delivery time.

Also, most cdn's offer certain optimisation techniques for content as well, so it's a good idea to check with your cdn provider what kind of optimisation they offer.

Further reading:
Google has written some stuff about this here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

For each file-type there are different rules, guidelines and best practises to follow when optimising. I'd advise reading up on optimisation techniques and supported codecs(video) for browser types etc.

Comment: Is it necessary to convert all image types to for example, .jpg files? Should I be concerned about supporting transparency in my images?

Comment: Not necessarily. You should probably just try out a few image optimisers. Most of them work well with any kind of image(even transparent ones). 

It's important to make sure you're not sending huge 1MB photos to a user when all they'll ever see of the image is a 32x32px thumb for example.